# Bower and folder structure

Tags: bower, bower-install

Let's say that I want to install jQuery UI. I do the command `bower install jquery-ui` and bower will download:

```
.
├── bower_components
│   ├── jquery
│   │   ├── dist
│   │   │   ├── jquery.js
│   │   │   └── jquery.min.js
│   │   └── src
│   └── jquery-ui
│       ├── themes
│       │   ├── smoothness
│       │   │   ├── jquery-ui.css
│       │   │   └── jquery-ui.min.css
│       │   └── [The rest of jQuery UI's themes]
│       ├── ui
│       │   ├── accordion.js
│       │   ├── autocomplete.js
│       │   └── ...
│       ├── jquery-ui.js
│       └── jquery-ui.min.js
└── index.html
```

after the download is finished to include the files in my index.html I'll have to write something like `bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js`, `bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js` and for the css `bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoo...` etc.

I'm used to work with a much simpler folder structure, like this:

```
.
├── css
│   ├── main.css
│   └── slider.css
├── js
│   ├── jquery.min.js
│   └── jquery-ui.min.js
├── index.html
├── contact.html
└── pricing.html
```

I want to know if there's any way I can make bower automatically download the `dist` files to my `css, js` folders regardless of what I'm installing?

Comment: using wiredep, you can specify overrides in the bower.json , and your files are automatically added to your page by wiredep

"overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    },
    "angular-toastr": {
      "main": [
        "dist/angular-toastr.css",
        "dist/angular-toastr.js",
        "dist/angular-toastr.tpls.js"
      ]
    }
  }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bower is used for one thing - to grab the latest version of those components and make sure you get all the files you need.

Bower does one job and is used as part of a "build pipeline". You're supposed to then use a second tool like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), or just a batch file/shell script with copy commands if you'd like, to copy only the files you need from `bower_components` into your desired folder structure. With Grunt and Gulp, this step can also include things like bundling or minification of scripts and stylesheets or even turning images into sprite sheets.

That said, if you don't mind dumping *all* the files Bower will pull down from a certain component into your structure (probably leaving a lot of crap you don't want, considering the details in your question), you can [use the .bowerrc file](http://bower.io/docs/config/) to change the output directory.

(TL;DR: Bower is like IKEA, delivering parts in flatpack - you can't put the package in the living room and expect it to be a table already, but you can write something that knows what's in the package and assemble exactly what you want without having to go hunt for the individual parts manually. Or you can just unpack the package once and take what you want manually and never use Bower again - there's nothing wrong with that.)

Comment: So, basically if I want to install jQuery, some slider, some color library, I'll have to create a batch file to move only the files I need. Like 2 lines of code for the slider, 2 for jQuery and so on... that's time consuming, I'll keep on doing it manually like I'm used to.

Comment: It requires adding those lines manually once per script/dependency/Bower package. It also wants for there to be a build process, which is very foreign for a static site and for many lightweight dynamic sites. It can be way too heavy-handed for many scenarios. If you do have it all set up, it does end up being less work when you bring more stuff in or want to make sure you've got the latest version of everything. But there's nothing wrong with *not* doing it like that either, I'm just saying that Bower is made to do step one and just get the component down to your disk and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I use **wiredep** with gulp.js or Grunt.js to include whatever dependencies my app needs:

- http://www.gulpjs.com
- http://www.npmjs.com/package/wiredep

It allows you to automatically insert any bower package your app needs to run.  Add "wiredep" as a task to any of your gulp.js or Grunt.js build tasks.